# cURL post request method

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Hello I have a problem with my cURL post request method. I need to get a content from an other host, so I got this method from http://php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php because I know that the destination host also uses cURL and gives a request to a service that executes an executable(exe).

```
    function postRequest($url, $data, $refer = "", $timeout = 10, $header = [])
{
    $curlObj = curl_init();
    $ssl = stripos($url,'https://') === 0 ? true : false;
    $options = [
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => 1,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)',
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => $timeout,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Expect:'],
        CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4,
        CURLOPT_REFERER => $refer
    ];
    if (!empty($header)) {
        $options[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $header;
    }
    if ($refer) {
        $options[CURLOPT_REFERER] = $refer;
    }
    if ($ssl) {
        //support https
        $options[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = false;
        $options[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
    }
    curl_setopt_array($curlObj, $options);
    $returnData = curl_exec($curlObj);
    if (curl_errno($curlObj)) {
        //error message
        $returnData = curl_error($curlObj);
    }
    curl_close($curlObj);
    return $returnData;
}
```

I call the method like this:

```
$command= array();

 $command["cmd"] = "D://Workspace/Interne_Entwicklung/Folder1/Folder2/Executable.exe " . "--command " . chr(34) .
                    "[{'filters': [ {'Z_RG_Generiert':0} ],auth:[{'userid':'gartner'}],'RequestId': 105.1,'Status': 0}]" . chr(34);
 echo postRequest("localhost:8080",$command);
```

and it returns me an **error** **("HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.")**
I already tried to add an option to the option array that defines the Content-Length to the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option like this:

```
$command= array();

 $command["cmd"] = "D://Workspace/Interne_Entwicklung/PreisigTest2/PreisigTest2/bin/Debug/PreisigTest2.exe " . "--command " . chr(34) .
                    "[{'filters': [ {'Z_RG_Generiert':0} ],auth:[{'userid':'gartner'}],'RequestId': 105.1,'Status': 0}]" . chr(34);
 $header=array();
 $header['Content-Length'] = strlen(json_encode($command));
 echo postRequest("localhost:8080",json_encode($command),"",10,$header)
```

So my question is:

- What is the reason for this message?
- How can I solve it, with defining a content-length or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

411 Code refers to **Length Required**. So here need to send Content-Length header as well.

```
$command= array();
$command["cmd"] = "D://Workspace/Interne_Entwicklung/PreisigTest2/PreisigTest2/bin/Debug/PreisigTest2.exe " . "--command " . chr(34) .
                    "[{'filters': [ {'Z_RG_Generiert':0} ],auth:[{'userid':'gartner'}],'RequestId': 105.1,'Status': 0}]" . chr(34);
 $header = array('Content-Length: ' . strlen(json_encode($command)));
 echo postRequest("localhost:8080",json_encode($command),"",10,$header);
```

Comment: Once try by using static header like curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-length: ".strlen(json_encode($data))));

Comment: it was this problem and a certivicate problem by the responsing host.